# How to using the .apply(lambda x: function) over all the columns of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, apply

I'm trying to pass every column of a dataframe through a custom function by using the apply(lamdba x: function in python.
The custom function I have created works individually but when put it into the apply(lamdba x: structure only returns NaN values into the selected dataframe.

first is the custom function -

```
def snr_pd(wavenumber_arr):
    intensity_arr = Zhangfit_output 
    signal_low = 1650
    signal_high = 1750
    noise_low = 1750
    noise_high = 1850

    signal_mask = np.logical_and((wavenumber_arr >= signal_low), (wavenumber_arr < 
    signal_high))
    noise_mask = np.logical_and((wavenumber_arr >= noise_low), (wavenumber_arr < noise_high))

    signal = np.max(intensity_arr[signal_mask])
    noise = np.std(intensity_arr[noise_mask])
    return signal / noise
```

And this is the setup of the lambda function -

```
sd['s/n'] = df.apply(lambda x: snr_pd(x), axis =0,)
```

Currently I believe this is taking the columns form df, passing them to the snr_pd() and appending them to sd under the column ['s/n'], but the only answer produced is NaN.

I have also tried a couple structure changes like using applymap() instead of apply().

```
sd['s/n'] = fd.applymap(lambda x: snr_pd(x), na_action = 'ignore')
```

However this return this error instead :

> ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation maximum which has no identity

Which I have even less understanding of.

Any help would be much apricated.

Comment: First, if you already have a defined function, simply pass it as a reference to `.apply()`. Using a `lambda` is only for cases where you need to define a function. Second, does your DataFrame have any `nan` values or non-numeric values? Third, where is `Zhangfit_output` defined? Fourth, it seems as though your function expects an array as input, but using `apply` maps a function to values of each column one-by-one, similar to `map(func, some_list)`.

Comment: There are no nan values on the dataframe and all values are numerical.
Zhangfit_output is from the package BaselineRemoval and is defind as :

`spec_obj = BaselineRemoval(fd[h]) Zhangfit_output = spec_obj.ZhangFit()`.

Can you explain the 4th part to me ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though your function `snr_pd()` expects an entire array as an argument.

Without seeing your data it's hard to say, but you *should* be able to apply the function directly to the DataFrame using [`np.apply_along_axis()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html):

```py
np.apply_along_axis(snr_pd, axis=0, arr=df)
```

Note that this assumes that every column in `df` is numeric. If not, then simply select the columns of the `df` on which you'd like to apply the function.

Note also that `np.apply_along_axis()` will return a numpy array.

Comment: Yeah every column represent an array.
do you mean the names of the columns or that the columns only have numbers in them ?
In this case they are, so this should work !
shall give it a try and report back.
thanks for the help

Comment: The change produces the same error of the second instance posted above

Comment: You're going to need to provide sample data, I can't help you debug something I can't see.

Comment: This produces the second error. Though having messed with the size with `df` it appear that the original `df` is to large to be processed all at once thus the second error.
that method should work with a break down of the `df`.

Comment: `df` is 2647 rows x 2011 columns, all data is numerical.
columns = ID , Wavenumber, Particle n, Particle n+1 ..... ect 

I dont know if I post the literal data

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20159305/6298712